# How can I return the first non-blank cell in a range of formulas?

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, match

I'm working with a spreadsheet that is used for data gathering. I've been asked to create an error checker for when data is pasted into the spreadsheet and overwrites the data validation rules.

In cells X3:AO33, I have a block of formulas. Most of them check for a blank cell, then check for valid entry in another cell. If the result is valid or not needed, it returns a blank. Otherwise, it returns a message. Here's an example:

`=IF(OR(AND(D3<>"",OR(F3="",G3="",H3="")),AND(U3<>"",V3="")),CONCATENATE("Required fields are missing in row ",ROW(),"."),"")`

Now I need to put something in B2 that looks for messages in the X3:AO33 range. I want it to return the value of the first non-blank cell. If Z5 has the first found error, then B2 should display the text in Z5. Then the user can fix the problem, which makes Z5 turn blank, and if the next error is in AB7, B2 should then display the text in AB7.

I've tried this.

`=INDEX(X3:AO33,MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(X3:AO33),0))`

And this.

`=INDEX(X3:AO33,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((X3:AO33<>0),0),0))`

And this.

`=INDEX(X3:AO33,MATCH(TRUE,LEN(X3:AO33)>0,0))`

And this.

`=MATCH("*",X3:AO33,0)`

I've tried them all as arrays and not as arrays. And they all bring back the #N/A error.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I improved my original formula. This will consistently get you the first non-blank going left to right, then down.  [See sample sheet](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AiO7_3PtXmZ9g6teWh7LBk23TZzVRA?e=RKa20T).

```
=LEFT(TEXTJOIN("??",TRUE,X3:AO30),FIND("??",TEXTJOIN("??",TRUE,X3:AO30))-1)
```

Also, you could use a custom function, that gives you the option to go up down or left right.

```
Function firstNoneBlank(theRange As Range, Optional upDownTrue As Boolean) As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long

Set theRange = Intersect(theRange, theRange.Worksheet.UsedRange)

For i = 1 To IIf(upDownTrue, theRange.Rows.Count, theRange.Columns.Count)
        For j = 1 To IIf(upDownTrue, theRange.Columns.Count, theRange.Rows.Count)
            If theRange.Cells(i, j).Value <> "" Then
                firstNoneBlank = theRange.Cells(i, j).Value
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next j
Next i

firstNoneBlank = "#AllBlanks"
End Function
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you! Much better than the helper column and 52-nested-IF-statement formula I had going for a while there.